# The potential of blender

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm 12 years old and new to Blender, and from what i've heard, blender is a really powerful tool, but i was wondering if I could make things like these in the following videos with like, a LOT of practice, I really am not sure if it's this powerful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39pGLfgecXs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwzH-t81MFw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpMqgUU2H5Y
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbQJkHzL4nQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJQOgMiFduU

Comment: Hi and welcome. Sure, just take a basic modeling/sculpting course and you'll be able to do that. Please consider that this is no regular forum rather a Q&A site and your question is way too broad for this site. The answer is: yes. If a *specific question* comes up while modeling, come back and ask it. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour and please read [How to ask a good question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck!

Comment: I wish I had started modelling at 12... Well to be honest there was no affordable 3D software back then :) Go on and start learning!

Comment: Hi! You might have some trouble with this question, because it might be considered too general for a technical Q&A site. BUT. Blender is easily capable of making all the models in these videos, and you might get the skills faster than you think, just take it step by step. This is exactly the sort of place to come when you get stuck. Folks will be very happy to help you out.

Comment: thanks guys, thats all I wanted to know :D